# Move specific UITextField when the Keyboard show

Tags: ios8, keyboard, xcode6, uitextfield

I followed the Apple documentation to move a textfield upwards when the keypad appears.
The code works fine my problem is that I need that one specific textfield is moved towards the other, instead of implementing the code Apple every textfield I select is moved upwards ... How can I do to move a specific textField and not all?

Thank you very much, I insert the following code used

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect bkgndRect = changePasswordTextField.superview.frame;
    bkgndRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, changePasswordTextField.frame.origin.y+kbSize.height) animated:YES];
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification {


    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your functionality by following steps.

1. Set delegate of your UITextField.
2. Implement `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method which will be called when keyboard open for textfield. So you may change frame of textfield in this method as below.

   ```
   -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
        [textField setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, textField.frame.origin.y-VALUE,textField.frame.size.width,textField.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
        // VALUE = textfield you want to move upward vertically
   }
   ```
3. Now, to handle keyboard hiding event, you can set frame of your textfield to its origin in `textFieldDidEndEditing` method as below.

   ```
   - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
         [textField setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, textField.frame.origin.y+VALUE,textField.frame.size.width,textField.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
         // VALUE = textfield you want to move downward vertically
   }
   ```

I hope it may help you.