# Custom Alert Notify iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, boolean

for my iOS app I created a custom UIView that has the function of "Custom Notifications".

Everything works fine, but I have a problem, I wish the notification to appear only once. In a nutshell my Case Study is that if I click several times the button that brings up the notification latter overlaps indefinitely, instead I would (perhaps through the use of a Boolean) be able to bring up a one-time notification also if the button is pressed several times ...

Could you advise the best way to achieve this?

**The custom view is presented in the external view controller in this way**

```
-(IBAction)loginUser:(id)sender {
    UTAlertView *alert = [[UTAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attenzione" message:@"Tutti i campi sono obbligatori" ];
        alert.alertViewType = UTAlertViewTypeWarning;
        [alert presentAlert];
        [self.view addSubview:alert];
}
```

**Custom UIView Class for Notification - Implementation file**

```
 @interface UTAlertView ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL alertActive;

@end

@implementation UTAlertView
@synthesize alertIcon;
@synthesize titleLabel, messageLabel;
@synthesize alertView;
@synthesize alertActive;



-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title message:(NSString *)message {
    [self initializeStringElementAlertView:title message:message];
    return self;
}

-(void)initializeStringElementAlertView:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message {
    alertView = [self initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height +100, kViewSize_W, kViewSize_H)];
    [UTAlertElement alertTitle:titleLabel withString:title andAddSubview:self];
    [UTAlertElement alertMessage:messageLabel withString:message andAddSubview:self];
    alertIcon = [UTAlertElement iconAlertViewInView:self];
}



-(void)presentAlert {

    if (!alertActive) {
        alertActive =YES;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                         animations:^{
                             [self bounce:1] ;

                             self.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height -60, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, kViewSize_H);

                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(setHideAnimation)];
                             tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
                             [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                             [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
                             [self performSelector:@selector(setHideAnimation) withObject:self afterDelay:3];

                         }];


    }

}


-(void)setHideAnimation {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                         animations:^{
                             self.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height +100, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, kViewSize_H);

                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            alertActive =NO;
                         }];




}
```

Comment: I think you should create a completeBlock. When you touch the button, you can set button.enable = No. And when the Alert show, you can call completeBlock and reset button.enable = Yes. Looklike: 
`- (void)showCustomAlert:(CustomAlert*)alert completeBlock:(void(^)())completionBlock {
    //show alert
    //do anything
    completionBlock();
}`

Comment: I tried with dispatch_once but the problem is that the notification does not come out more .. I fully understand the use of dispatch_once but what I need is that the action of the button is repeated only when the animation is finished ...

Example: exit notification, waits three seconds and then disappears, only this time in the next notification should appear, I do not want the notification can be presented during the animation of the first notification

Comment: @rory In that case you should be more clear in your question to state this. As it is now, it can easily be interpreted to be a one-time-only notification. If you only want to avoid the notification to be presented multiple times at once, you could use a block, delegate, singleton or simple just keep a boolean flag. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: YES Steffen! it is just that I need ... I am creating are notifications such as "The user name is incorrect" notification is displayed when the user clicks the button "Login" (in the Login), so I do not want that reporting is to be superimposed in case there is a double-click of the button . I hope to be able to explain to me.

Comment: @SteffenD.Sommer  The second notification must occur only when the first has finished the whole process of animation that is its presentation and his disappearance after 3 three seconds. only now vogli that a second notification can be shown. Sorry if I can not explain with right terms also my English is really worth :(

Comment: @rory Can you provide some details on how you show/hide the notification?

Comment: @SteffenD.Sommer ... Sure! i'm edit my post!  I am waiting for your advice

Comment: @SteffenD.Sommer advice??

Comment: @rory I'm updating my answer right now :)

Comment: @rory Have a look now. Let me know if you're still struggling.

Comment: @SteffenD.Sommer ok i'm testing

Comment: @SteffenD.Sommer  I just edited my post with the file implementation of my custom UIView class and I have changed thanks to your advice. But still the notification overlaps.
As you understand I have a custom UIView class that creates the notification and in another view controller I have the button that the user pushes to login ... If this button is pushed repeatedly notifications overlap yet, where am I doing wrong?

Comment: @rory The problem is that you're creating the notification every time the user clicks the button. I can update my answer to show what to do.

Comment: @rory Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, now it works ... that's where the mistake was ... now looking to see how to make the code more aesthetically 'beautiful ... my initial idea was to create this whole function within the custom UIView class and then in the view controller with 4 lines of code to start the notification without problems .. Anyway you have been very kind and I thank you very much for your help, you saved me !!!

Comment: @SteffenD.Sommer I was left with only this as a block to move along and here I could not find a solution ... if you do not create problems and does not make you waste time you could take a look at this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141340/move-specific-uitextfield-when-the-keyboard-show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply just want your code to execute only, then have a look at `dispatch_once` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/dispatch_once_t).

Basically you can just do:

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^ { 
    // Your code to be executed only once.
});
```

If you want to be able to open the notification multiple times, but not at the same time, you have multiple options, including:

- The singleton pattern: I would not use this in this case as this would mean that you won't be able to have multiple instances of your notification type.
- Blocks or delegate: Having a completion block or using the delegate pattern could also be an option. However, I think that this approach would leave it up to the consumer of the notification class to handle the logic of when it should be possible to show the notification. This might be what you want (if you have different logic on different views), but I don't think so.

These could be good approaches, but in your case I would simply go with some basic state handling, as you suggest yourself. So, I would probably do something like this:

**Step 1: Add the BOOL property to your notification class**

`@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isVisible`

**Step 2: Add state handling to your show and hide methods**

```
-(void)presentAlert {
    //PRESENT THE ALERT
    if (!self.isVisible) {
        self.isVisible = YES;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                         animations:^{
                             [self bounce:1];
                             self.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 60, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, kViewSize_H);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(setHideAnimation)];
                             tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
                             [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                             [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
                             [self performSelector:@selector(setHideAnimation) withObject:self afterDelay:3];
                         }];
    }
}

-(void)setHideAnimation {
    //REMOVE THE ALERT
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                     animations:^{
                         self.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height +100, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, kViewSize_H);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         self.isVisible = NO;
                    }];
}
```

I haven't really tested it, but it should get you started. Also, you might want to look into avoiding retain cycles.

Remember that when using this approach you should not create the notification every time the user triggers the notification. You probably want to do something like:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) UTAlertView *loginAlert;`

And then when you setup the view (e.g. in `viewDidLoad` or `loadView`) you can create the notification:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.loginAlert = [[UTAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attenzione" message:@"Tutti i campi sono obbligatori" ];
    self.loginAlert.alertViewType = UTAlertViewTypeWarning;
}
```

And of course, then in your method that is responsible of showing the alert would do something like:

```
-(IBAction)loginUser:(id)sender {
    [self.loginAlert presentAlert];
    [self.view addSubview:self.loginAlert];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a single instance (Singleton) alert will solve your problem. Use the singleton pattern to avoid multiple instance of alert view appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCD `dispatch_once`.

For example in init method of your view create `dispatch_once_t dispatch_flag` and then:

```
  dispatch_once( & dispatch_flag, ^{
    // your presentation code goes here
  } );
```

Comment: dispatch_flag   I return an error ... why?... I was wrong to write in some way? excuse but are new to xcode ... could you show me an example implementation?

Comment: I tried to implement what I've recommended, but I did not get results ... the custom view overlaps every time I push the button ... Where am I doing wrong?                                                                                                                           

 dispatch_once( & dispatch_flag, ^{
        [self presentAlert];
    } );